# Using Euclid's algorithm to solve $341x \equiv 15 \pmod{912}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

$$341x \equiv 15 \pmod{912}$$

First, I found the GCD between $341$ and $912$ using Euclid's algorithm:

$$912 = 341 \cdot 2 + 230$$
$$341 = 230 \cdot 1 + 111$$
$$230 = 111\cdot2 + 8$$
$$111 = 8 \cdot 13 + 7$$
$$8 = 7\cdot 1 + 1$$
$$1 = 1\cdot1 + 0$$
Hence, GCD$(912, 341) = 1$. Then, per Bezout's identity, I rewrote $1$ as a linear product: $912p + 341q$.

We have that:

$$230 = 912 - 341 \cdot 2$$
$$111 = 341 - 230\cdot 1$$
$$8 = 230 - 111\cdot2$$
$$7 = 111 - 8\cdot13$$
$$1 = 8-7\cdot1$$

Therefore, $1 = 912\cdot43 - 341\cdot 115$.
This, as per my understanding (absolutely do tell me if I'm wrong) should mean that $115$ is the inverse of $341$ modulo $912$.

Therefore, here's what I did:
$$341x = 15 \pmod{912}$$
$$341 \cdot 115 x \equiv 1\cdot x \equiv 15\cdot 115 = 1725 \pmod{912}$$
$$x \equiv 1725 \pmod{912}$$
Now, subbing $1725$ for its remainder from the division by $912$, we have:
$$x = -99 \pmod{912}$$
However, the correct answer is $x \equiv 99 \pmod{912}$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1=912\cdot43−341\cdot115$$
This is correct.  However, this means that $-115$ is the inverse of $341$, since your expression should be of the form $1=ax+by$.  Multiplying both sides by $-115$, you would get the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you! It was such an obvious mistake. I am new to this stuff haha.

Comment: @SamueleB. It's not at all obvious when it's surrounded by so much correct work! ^_^  One thing that helps me to check work like this is that the default scientific calculator in Windows 10 has a mod button to double check the key points in your explanation to see where the arithmetic went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, man. As a little bit of a side question, why doesn't the method I used here seem to work (at least immediately) for another equation such as $70x\equiv222\pmod{24}$? Is the problem the fact that the whole equation could be divided by $2$ first, here?

Comment: @SamueleB. It we reduce the Bezout equation mod $912$ we obtain $1\equiv -341(115)\equiv 341(\color{#c00}{-115})\,$ so $\,341^{-1}\equiv \color{#c00}{-115}.\,$ *That's* the best way to view it (vs. pattern-matching in Bezout) since it reveals the *arithmetical* essence of the matter.